# How to display colors correctly using ::selection pseudo element

Tags: css

I'm styling the selected text in my document using the ::selection pseudo class.

```css
div::selection {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

span {
  color:white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Selected styled.</div>

Selected regular.

<span>Not Selected.</span>
```

When I select the styled text, the red is very visibly not the same color as regular red. It has a blue-ish overlay. This seems to be some sort of interaction between the default selection styles of the browser and my own styles.

How can I completely remove the browsers styling while keeping my own?

I've tried using `user-select: none;` in the html style, but that completely overrides all selection.

EDIT: I've just run this is firefox and it's fine, so this appears to be a Chrome specific issue.

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of what I see when selecting: [image: Selected Text]

I'm using Google Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131 on a Mac.

Comment: Disagree, they look the same to me.

Comment: what version of Chrome, it's also fine for me

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Version 74.0.3729.131 on a Mac

Comment: There _is_ a slight difference (in the screenshot at least): 'Selected styled' is #ff3943 and 'Not Selected' is #f00

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in Chromium in Linux. Apparently, the opacity of the background is not 1. Setting `opacity` explicitly has no effect though.